# Display BLOB image data to view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

GOAL: I'm trying to display an Image into my Laravel 7 view, retrived directly from database.

**In my MySQL WORKBENCH:**
[image]

PROCESS:

1. As you can see in my controller **JobsController**, I will select and retrieve the image from database, identified by `jobs $job_name`.

[image]

As you can see here, I tried to `dd($job_name)` and we can see that BLOB data in `$job_image` variable. I will pass this Collection object to view and display it directly.

[image]

Most SO questions relate to displaying the image using `<img src="myFileName"/>`.
Problem is I'm not storing it as a file but instead just retrieve and display it directly. I just want to dump all the variables into my view file like other job details.

Solutions tried in my view file.

1. `<img>{{ base64_encode($job_details->job_image) }}</img>`. Failed. Output is "*/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQ*".
2. `<img>{{ base64_decode($job_details->job_image) }}</img>`. I don't have much understanding about what encoding and decoding happens when data is stored and retrieved from and to the database. Here I decoded the variable. No output.
3. `<img src="{{ $job_details->job_image}}"/>`. This is dumb, src attribute expects an PATH.

So there, none of these would turn the variable content into an image. 
Please tell me what I am missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this**

```
$image = 'your_image_blob_name';

$imageData = base64_encode(file_get_contents($image));

$src = 'data: '.mime_content_type($image).';base64,'.$imageData;

echo '<img src="'.$src.'">';
```

Comment: Thanks! Such a detailed answer. 
I like how the mime_content_type make the file types dynamic dpending on the original file.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there. You have to use the base64 string in the src attribute. Make sure you also include the data type and other relevant information at the beginning. See: [How to display Base64 images in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499633/how-to-display-base64-images-in-html)

Comment: Thanks! Sounds so ridiculous that I'm just missing 1 step there. LOL!
But who would have guessed that <img> SRC attrib accepts that kind of magic.